# Highcharts maps (even samples) don't work

Tags: highcharts

Running MacOS 10.13.5 and Windows 10 in Parallels. Load Highcharts samples from https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/color-axis ... the map background is gray and the states only fill in as I mouse over them.

This happens in both MacOS and in Windows. Screenshot is from Highcharts site.

[image: Moused over just two states]

EDIT Per comment I edited to look like this (since I display both charts and maps from same module):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<!-- USE MASTER BRANCH OF HIGHCHARTS MAPPING AND NOT RELEASE VERSION **** TEMP *** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051239/highcharts-maps-even-samples-dont-work
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4.js"></script>
    -->

<!--
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>

    -->

<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/master/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/master/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/master/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/master/maps/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>
```

But I get error 16. I assume I should pull all the libs from github but it looks like as well some of the names have changed?

Comment: Looks like issue with libraries being pulled right now. Did you try using a locally hosted page?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this bug is already **fixed** on master branch of Highcharts:

```
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/master/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/master/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/master/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/master/maps/modules/offline-exporting.js">
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/teazgj5r/

Fix will be included in the next release of Highmaps.

Comment: Thanks very much, much appreciated.

Comment: See edits to main post -- I now get Error 16 which I suspect means release libs for charting and github libs for mapping are out of sync?

Comment: The cause of this error is that you imported both `highcharts` and `highmaps` - `highmaps` code already contains full `highcharts` code. You should import maps as a module in this case: `<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/master/modules/map.js"></script>`

It's explained on this documentation page: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started